# Откуда берется наименование папки с настройками приложения?

Tags: c#, .net

Я пользуюсь стандартным способом хранения настроек приложения `Properties\Settings.settings`

Настройки помещаются в файл по примерно такому пути: `%LOCALAPPDATA%\MyApp\MyApp.exe_Url_l2acnwn1eoostrlvwy2ik02hnoqwsfuq\1.0.0.0\user.config`

Откуда берется название приложения `MyApp` и как его получить в коде?

Я пробовал менять в настройках `Assembly name` - изменилась только часть `MyApp.exe_Url_l2acnwn1eoostrlvwy2ik02hnoqwsfuq`, но `MyApp` не изменилась.

Пробовал править `Title` и `Product` в `Assembly Information` - безрезультатно, меняются только свойства приложения, путь к настройкам не меняется.

При смене версии приложения в `Assembly Information` меняется только часть пути, ответственная за версию (логично): `1.0.0.0`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Путь к конфигурации имеет следующий вид:

`%LOCALAPPDATA%\(Company name)\(EXE file name)_(AppDomain ID)\(Version)\user.config`

*(Company name)* - это имя компании, которое берется из атрибута `AssemblyCompany` в свойствах сборки.

```
var ass = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
var attr =  ass.GetCustomAttributes( typeof(System.Reflection.AssemblyCompanyAttribute),true);
if (attr.Length > 0)
{
    string company = ((System.Reflection.AssemblyCompanyAttribute)attr[0]).Company;                    
}
```

Если этот атрибут пустой или состоит из неподходящих символов, вместо него .NET пытается использовать аналогичную строку из `FileVersionInfo`. Если и она пустая, используется первая (до точки) часть пространства имен, в котором расположен класс *Program* (`assembly.EntryPoint.ReflectedType.Namespace`). Полный алгоритм выбора этой строки можно посмотреть в [исходнике](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Configuration/System/Configuration/ClientConfigPaths.cs,17d647bae0e63e77,references).

Итоговый путь к конфигу можно получить программно так (добавить ссылку на System.Configuration):

```
System.Configuration.Configuration config =
    System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(
    System.Configuration.ConfigurationUserLevel.PerUserRoamingAndLocal                
);
MessageBox.Show(config.FilePath);
```

Comment: хм, а если там пустая строка? (у меня именно так)

Comment: Добавил `AssemblyCompany` - берется теперь оно, но вот если его нет, не понятно...

Comment: @АндрейNOP Там берется либо из данных версии файла, либо пространство имен. Обновил.

Comment: Круто, спасибо! Вы смогли-таки распутать этот клубок в referencesource! Проверил: изменил пространство имен с App-файлом (у меня WPF-проект) - изменилось и местоположение файла с настройками.