# Работа с фото WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, файлы

```
OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
openFileDialog.ShowDialog();
PhotoPath = openFileDialog.FileName;
string fileName = PhotoPath.Skip(PhotoPath.IndexOf(PhotoPath.Last(p => p == '\\'))).ToString();
File.Move(PhotoPath, @"\Resources\"); //Тут исключение
var img = new BitmapImage(new Uri($@"\Resources\{fileName}"));
UserPhoto_Ellipse.Fill = new ImageBrush(img);
```

По задумке, получаем ссылку на фото, переносим его в папку с ресурсами, и вставляем фото в качестве заливки для `Ellipse`. 
Ошибка:

> System.UnauthorizedAccessException: "Отказано в доступе по данному пути."

Как решить?

Comment: Зачем переносите? Права на запись у приложения точно есть? Папка существует? Какой абсолютный путь фактически соответствует вашему относительному `@"\Resources\"`?

Comment: @АндрейNOP переношу, что бы дальше использовать файл при запуске в виде аватарки, папка существует. Папка прокта. К проекту подключена папка, и хотелось бы туда её. А вот насчёт прав не знаю... как можно проверить?

Comment: @АндрейNOP или для моей цели лучше использовать другой вариант?

Comment: Папку проекта лучше не использовать, например, обычно приложения устанавливаются в "Program Files", писать в которую не разрешено. Используйте "%LOCALAPPDATA%" (см.: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/787805/218063)

Comment: @АндрейNOP так делать не стоит? https://pastenow.ru/196d64ba7fe9b3cfeba577c9ada609a7

Comment: То что в SolutionExplorer — оно будет в скомпилированном приложении, вы же хотите добавлять картинки во время исполнения, так делать не желательно, я написал почему. Если ваше приложение будет портативным — делать можно, но убедитесь, что папка существует (`Directory.Exists`)

Comment: @АндрейNOP так. Приложение портативное, хочу сделать что бы человек скачал приложение, установил, и зайдя в него смог выбрать фото на компьютере и оно могло и дальше использоваться даже если его там нету. Где проблема?

Comment: Что выдает `Path.GetFullPath(@"\Resources\")`?

Comment: @АндрейNOP С:\\Resources\

Comment: А вот так `Path.GetFullPath(@"Resources\")`?

Comment: @АндрейNOP в ответ, уважаемый. Как вы это делаете??